# Model generation for manually entered page in Spring framework

Tags: java, model, spring

I have to extend some Spring web application, but I'm not very familiar with the framework (however, I have some experience with few other frameworks). I can see that there is "ModelAndView" concept used by the framework. Controller returns both: a model and a view from onSubmit() method. But what to do if a model have to be generated for a page entered manually (user enters the page address to the browser address bar, instead of submitting a form). In such a case there is no onSubmit() call, so a model isn't prepared.

I thought of (ab)using formBackingObject() method of BaseFormController class, which prepares "command" object. But I don't know how to refer the object in the jsp code. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the [supported HTTP methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-controller-abstractcontroller) of the controller with the [supportedMethods property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/WebContentGenerator.html#setSupportedMethods%28java.lang.String[]%29). The default values are HEAD, GET and POST. If the same parameters are sent with a GET request (there are some restrictions on what can be transmitted) there should be no difference from the controller perspective.

It has to be noted that the HTTP methods have a semantic that should not be broken: get to retrieve (without changes), post to manipulate etc.

Answer (score 0):

The proper method to override to provide model data for the "initial" view is [referenceData()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html#referenceData(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)). As you can see in the Javadoc, there are two overloads of this method, depending on what you need to do.

> Create a reference data map for the given request and command, consisting of bean name/bean instance pairs as expected by ModelAndView.
>
> The default implementation delegates to `referenceData(HttpServletRequest)`. Subclasses can override this to set reference data used in the view.